# copy and paste same non contiguous cells from different sheets to master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

how to copy same non contiguous cell from different sheets and paste in one master sheets ("sheet5") row by row.

```
Sub test()

    Dim cel As Range, pasteRange As Range

    Set pasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A2")

    For i=1 to 4
        For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("A2, B4, D5, E1, F3")
            pasteRange.Value = cel.Value
            Set pasteRange = pasteRange.Offset(0, 1)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cel As Range, pasteRange As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

' Do not use 'ThisWorkbook' - what is the macro us ran from another one?
' Use 'ActiveWorkbook' instead or specify its name
Set pasteRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A2")

'
For Each sht In Sheets
    If sht.name <> "Sheet5" Then
        For Each cel In sht.Range("A2, B4, D5, E1, F3")
            pasteRange.Value = cel.Value
            Set pasteRange = pasteRange.Offset(0, 1)
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: hi Michal..I appreciate your answer but I want the contiguous cell data to display in a tabular form for instance sheet1(A2:E2),sheet2(A3:E3),sheet3(A4:E4) etc